# Horror short story about an upscale restaurant, the regulars of which eventually disappear and are served as the next meal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I read it in a horror anthology a while ago.  I don't remember too much of it, but it was about an upscale restaurant which only served limited plates for regulars who would disappear once in a while, with the implication being that they were being fed and fattened up to be the next meal at the restaurant.

I think the narrator may have been a restaurant reviewer, or someone whose friend finally allowed him to tag along.

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out!

"[Specialty of the House](http://mysteriouspress.com/products/edgar-award-authors-winners-and-nominees/the-specialty-of-the-house-by-stanley-ellin.asp)" (1956) by Stanley Ellin.

> In Sbirro’s restaurant, there is no electric lighting, no music, and no menu. The only sound is the contented sighs of the regulars, who come every night in hopes that Sbirro will treat them to his signature dish, the famed lamb Amirstan, which comes from a beast so rare, only Sbirro knows how to obtain it. Tonight, two diners at this spectacular relic of a forgotten age will find that lamb Amirstan costs more than they are willing to pay.

Comment: Excellent! You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons 48 hours from when you asked it, so a little less than two days from now.

Comment: I love that intro, it sounds like what you'd hear at the start of a Twilight Zone episode